# How to solve this partial differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following $$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \rho^2}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \rho}=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$ with boundary conditions $$T(\rho, 0)=f(\rho) \qquad 0 \leq \rho \leq 1$$ and $$T(1,t)=0$$

Using *Mathematica*.

I tried

`DSolve[D[T[r, t], {r, 2}] + (1/r)*D[T[r, t], r] = (1/a)*D[T[r, t], t], T[r, t], {r, t}]`

but it gives me error.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (assuming alpha must be squared)

```
PDE = D[T[r, t], {r, 2}] + (1/r)*D[T[r, t], r] == 1/a^2*D[T[r, t], t];

DSolve[{PDE, T[r, 0] == f[r], T[1, t] == 0}, T[r, t], {r, t}]
```